# roundcube doesn't login after installation

Tags: roundcube, ispconfig

I was trying installing roundcube on my apache2,ISPCONFIG3 server, on my LAN  using :
https://www.howtoforge.com/using-roundcube-webmail-with-ispconfig-3-on-debian-wheezy-apache2
with the following changes :
remoteuser roundcube
pass password809098
and
https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-roundcube-webmail-on-ubuntu-20-04/
with these changes :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON roundcube.* TO roundcubeuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/roundcube.jungsf.tv.conf
a2ensite roundcube.jungsf.tv
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName roundcube.jungsf.tv 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/roundcube/

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube.jungsf.tv_error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/roundcube.jungsf.tv_access.log combined

    Options FollowSymLinks
<Directory "/var/www/roundcube/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
<Directory "/var/www/roundcube/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I managed at end to get the roundcube web interface through http://jungsf.tv/webmail
but it still doesn't log in, I don't know which password/username should be,
I tried all combinations roundcube/roundcubeuser/email .... password,PASSWORD,password809098

how can I find the user/pass or how can I delet everything to reinstall it ?
I saw this plugin to set pass, but how can I use it ?
https://github.com/saas-dev/roundcube-forgot_password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to work it by creating mailbox in ispconfig3, there I entered email and pass which are used to login in roundcube.